# Fine-grained flag permissions

Tags: 7, flags

Is it possible to control permissions relating to flags more closely, either in flag.module or by installing another module? I'd like to be able to control permissions for each flag, such as "Flag content with this flag", "unflag content with this flag", "view this flag" etc etc.

Comment: are you asking about doing this on a per user basis?  most of what you are asking is already available on a per role basis.

Comment: Yes, it would be on a per user basis: each flag would effectively be "owned" by a specific user, who would have exclusive rights to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a 'local' flag? Flags are already separated into global and local flags. For example, a global flag might be 'report this comment' and once one person flags the comment it is flagged for everyone. Local flags on the other hand are unique for each user, so for example a 'bookmark this' flag would only be for the current user context and other users wouldn't be able to modify their flags. From the documentation:

> Flags may be per-user, meaning that each user can mark an item
>   individually, or global, meaning that the item is either marked or it
>   is not marked, and any user who changes that changes it for everyone.

You set whether a flag is global or local when you create it.

Comment: No, I was looking for greater control on which users could set which flags. I'm going to be using a different technique, though. Thanks for taking the time to offer an answer.